# Simultaneous async API calls in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, declarative

I've been using hooks in my React project for a while now and have developed a hook for getting data, similar to many others, which I use like this.

```
const [callApi, isLoading, result, errrors] = useData();
```

callApi is a function which you call with your data and axios config, it makes the API call and updates the other variables. I deal with the result in a useEffect() call which sets the state when it receives new data. It's fairly simple.

The problem is that while it works very well for one request at a time, it has a single isLoading state and a single result state, which is no good if it's called before the previous call is finished. Let's say my user sending a message to his friends and the UI shows a list of friends with a "send message" button next to each name, they might click 3 buttons and make 3 calls in quick succession. We then have a race condition to see which one sets the result first.

I'm used to imperative programming with promises, in my old Angular code the button click would call an event handler which would call the api and the promise .then() would then deal with the result. This could happen 100 times simultaneously and each one would resolve seperately and then update the UI.

So my question is, is there an idiomatic way of doing this declaratively using react hooks so that I can fire off multiple requests and deal with the loading/result/errors separately?

Comment: This seems likes a feature that would be better handled via your API by using a queue. Is that something within your control?

Comment: Use a queue (array) inside of `useData()` that tracks how many pending requests there are. When a new request is made, add the unresolved promise to the queue. When the promise resolves, remove it from the queue. `isLoading` would equal `true` if the length of the queue is greater than zero.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo In this instance yes, but in many instances no. For example, if I was calling a zip code look up inside a typeahead box each time the user typed a letter.

Comment: @jered , what about the multiple results which come back? will my useEffect() function run for each result, even if the result is identical for them all? In an imperative version of this code each call would resolve a promise with a different result, not update the same result variable.

Comment: If there can only ever be a single `result`, then you simply discard the previous Promise when a new one is created, and only update the `result` when the most recent Promise resolves.

Comment: I’d suggest you post a bit more of your code, both useData and where it is used.

Comment: It needs to deal with multiple simultaneous calls and their results before the next result comes along. My code is complicated but I will try to simplify it to make an example. In the meantime I may have solved it by changing my philosophy a bit... Having a child component for each row in my table would give me the ability to give each button it's own data loading service with it's own "isLoading" and "result" variables.